# Bookmarklet error when running script

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I have code is this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DFWrw/7/)

I have it in a script called AutoPolicy.js at the same location, which I'm trying to call using a bookmarklet:

```
javascript: (function(){document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('script')).src='http://localhost:43911/Scripts/AutoPolicy.js';})();
```

When I run this in chrome (not tried other browsers yet), I get an error:

**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL** Sorry - I can't seem to find any more information on the error.

Waat is causing this error and why does it run on jsFiddle but not when called from the bookmarklet?

Thanks

Davy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that it is the paren just after the `createElement` which is misplaced (attribute `src` is for the script element and not the `document.body`) :

```
javascript: (function(){document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('script').src='http://localhost:43911/Scripts/AutoPolicy.js');})();
```

---

**EDIT**

Edited code in order to separate the treatments:

```
javascript:(function(){var%20src='http://localhost:43911/Scripts/AutoPolicy.js',s=document.createElement('script');s.src=src;document.body.appendChild(s);})();
```

Comment: thanks - 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;' with that syntax.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry : I have again misplaced the paren : it should go just before the `; `. I have edited my post.

Comment: no sorry - still no joy.  I don't understand as its been working fine.

Comment: It seems that source should be attributed independantly : I have succeeded to make it works (I have tested with jQuery UI) with the new code indicated in the post.